# How does Android Auto media App shows up when connected to phone?

Tags: android, android-auto

How does Android Auto media App shows up when connected to phone.

I implemented Android auto media app, added 
 in xml,

When I connect my phone to car, I see only google play music app not my custom app. Does MediaBrowserService implemented as well?

Manifest file: `

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Tunes"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

In order for your app to show up in a real car, your app must be installed from the Google Play store.  This means that you must submit it to Google for their review.  They then sign the apk and make it available through the Store.  It also has to pass certain Android Auto requirements to be placed in the Production store.  You can submit the app through the Alpha channel and they can possibly give you a provisional approval to proceed if it doesn't quite meet all of the standards.  This is the only way it will appear in an actual car.  Their requirements are here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/auto.html

Also, once your app is submitted to the Store, it usually takes a few hours before it is reviewed and approved.  This makes quick test/fix cycles hard to do.

You can also download the Desktop Head Unit (DHU) and test your Android Auto app in this simulator before submitting it to the store.  More information is here: https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html.  This simulator does not require the apk to be signed first so you can test/fix quickly before submitting your app to Google.

Comment: And why isn't this prominently noted in Google's [Android Auto tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/audio/index.html)?  I implemented all the code they indicate, paying attention to ensure that my app is doing everything Google says it _must_.  Then multiple baffled trips to/from the car wondering why it's not appearing.